# Why do I keep getting a write cannot be an int, but when I convert it to a string, I get "Please enter an number"

Tags: python

```
def pinchange() : 
    while True : 
        user_passwordpinchange = str(input("Please enter the correct password"))
        try : 
            if str(user_passwordpinchange) == str(password) : 
                print("Correct password")
                newpassword = str(input("Enter new password here"))
                newpassword = pinpasswordfilename1.write(str(newpassword))
                newpassword = str(password)
                pinpasswordfilename1.close()
                break
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include only the necessary code, exact details of an error and everything else to produce a [**minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Amongs other things, this includes for example replacing all the `input()` calls with actual data causing you error.

Comment: Attach complete Traceback error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: add what step you have taken so other can replicate and can help you

Comment: Nothing in your code is going to cause a prompt "Please enter an number"

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to pass an open file handle into a function that might close it. Better to pass the file name and get the function to manage the opening and closing.

You may find the following pattern useful:

```
def pinchange(filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as password_file:
        old_password = password_file.readline().strip()
        while True:
            check_password = input('Current password: ')
            if check_password == old_password:
                new_password = input('New password: ')
                password_file.seek(0)
                password_file.write(new_password)
                password_file.truncate()
                break
            print('\aIncorrect password')
```

**Note:**

This will fail if the file doesn't exist or if it's empty. You'll need to introduce further checks to account for that potentiality

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that in pinchange, pinpasswordfilename1 is no longer an open file handle,

```
def pinchange() : 
    while True : 
        user_passwordpinchange = str(input("Please enter the correct password"))
        try : 
            if str(user_passwordpinchange) == str(password) : 
                 print("Correct password")
                 newpassword = str(input("Enter new password here"))
                 with open("D:\\hi.txt", "w") as pinpasswordfilename1:
                      pinpasswordfilename1.write(str(newpassword))
                 break
```

should fix it

Comment: Why are you calling *str()* on objects that are already strings? This code is not runnable

Comment: My response was based on the original question, that included the complete runnable code, (and I responded with a fix for the broken function in the complete context)

Comment: The code in the OP's original question is **not** runnable. Neither is your "answer"

Comment: Originally, the OP posted a complete example, that was runnable, and only failed in case when one used the pinchange function, but he since reduced it down to just the pinchange function, the original version runs, it only needs a hi.txt file with an initial password) and produced the described error. While I wrote my answer, the OP changed the question.